# Como exportar todos los post de wordpress a un archivo XML con php?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

Quisiera saber si alguien sabe como exportar todos los post de mi sitio en wordpress por medio de codigo PHP, que tomara datos como titulo del post, imagen destacada , contenido los ponga en su respectiva etiqueta y lo guarde en un archivo XML en el servidor y que se actualizara con cada post nuevo que se creara, en orden de fecha mas reciente a la mas antigua espero y alguien me pueda ayudar, por que estoy creando una aplicacion para android y necesito como fuente de datos el archivo XML gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción es usar la API JSON de WordPress, obteniendo los posts con la API HTTP de WordPress, y después convertir el array obtenido en XML.

1. Tienes que utilizar el [plugin que habilita los endpoint JSON](http://torquemag.io/2014/08/introduction-wordpress-new-universal-connector-json-rest-api/).
2. La función wp_remote_get de la API HTTP de WordPress te permite hacer una consulta, guardando la respuesta completa (incluyendo headers) en una variable.

   `$response = wp_remote_get('http://local.wp.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/');`

Tip: puedes agregar ?_embed para que incluya etiquetas, categorías y otros datos, empotrados completos en cada post, y no solo el ID relacionado.

3. El JSON que representa los posts (la R en REST), lo recuperas con:

   `$json = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);`
4. Conviertes el JSON en un array con json_decode.

   `$array = json_decode( $json, $assoc = true );`
5. Convertir el array que obtuviste en XML, dependiendo de la versión de PHP con la que estés trabajando puedes optar por una librería moderna o clases propias.

Si ya trabajas con PHP 5.6 puedes usar FluidXML, que viene relacionado en una pregunta similar a esta (convertir array a XML) en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34970445/1778979

Si aún sigues trabajando con PHP 5.2, la respuesta siguiente te da una clase con la que puedes trabajar para resolver el problema

Además tienes que incluir la imagen destacada (thumbnail) en el JSON, porque no la incluye WordPress por default, espero te sirva este código que yo estoy usando para este mismo propósito (aunque yo no necesito la conversión a XML), lo tienes que incluir en un plugin específico de tu sitio, o en el functions.php del tema activo:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_thumbnail_field_for_posts');

function register_thumbnail_field_for_posts()
{
    register_rest_field('post', 'thumbnail', [
        'get_callback' => 'get_thumbnail_of_post',
        'update_callback' => null,
        'schema' => [
            'description' => 'Imagen destacada del post',
            'type' => 'string',
            'format' => 'url',
            'context' => ['view'],
            'readonly' => true,
        ]
    ]);
}

function get_thumbnail_of_post($object, $field_name, $request)
{
    $attachment_id = get_post_meta($object['id'], '_thumbnail_id', true);
    if (!$attachment_id) {
        return;
    }
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
    return $url;
}
```

Notas y otras referencias (no puedo poner más vínculos).

- Busca en wordpress.org por WordPress REST API (Version 2) (no me deja compartirte aquí el vínculo).

Comment: ¿y el plugin que no hace lo que el OP está preguntando es mejor?

Comment: No, es igual...

Comment: Incluí código propio para que el OP pueda obtener el thumbnail de los posts en el JSON devuelto por WP, el gist de obtener el JSON desde el mismo WP con su API HTTP, y referencias a soluciones para convertir el array en XML, no puedo ser más preciso porque desconozco que estructura de XML espera y no sabemos que versión de PHP utiliza. Espero la respuesta le ayude mejor.

Comment: No estoy 100% seguro, pero creo que con 50 Rep ya puede poner más vínculos .

Comment: Probablemente, vengo arrastrando la costumbre de enlazar referencias en lugar de dar soluciones completas, gracias por tu retroalimentación, efectivamente estoy más satisfecho con una respuesta más amplia.

Comment: Genial y de nada. Esta muy buena tu respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por responder, creo que este código me va ayudar, lo único sería el orden de los post, como puedo manipularlos para que en el xml me aparezcan primero los post más nuevos a los más antiguos? Ahorita mismo no puedo probar el código estoy fuera de casa pero llegando me aplico y les cuento.

Comment: De manera predeterminada, la API de WordPress devuelve los posts en ese orden (primero más recientes). Puedes pasar otros argumentos para filtrar o reordenar la consulta, los que admite los puedes consultar con una consulta de método **OPTIONS** al endpoint, por ejemplo: _http://ejemplo.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/_ te recomendaría [Insomnia](http://insomnia.rest) para esto. Para orden, se llama orderby.

Comment: Hola de nuevo ya estoy implementando el codigo, creo que vamos por buen camino, nadamas algo que no me queda claro al ultimo, cuando convierta el array a XML con fluidXML como lo guardo en un archivo?? por ejemplo en el directorio raiz, Gracias de antemano

Comment: Pues con base en el ejemplo de [añadir un array al objeto fluidxml](https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml), solamente necesitas usar las funciones estándar de PHP, tipo: [$file = fopen('archivo.xml', 'w'); fwrite($file, $fluidXml); fclose($file);](http://aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=585:leer-y-escribir-archivos-de-texto-con-php-funcion-fopen-modo-fgets-fputs-fclose-y-feof-ejemplo-cu00836b-&catid=70:tutorial-basico-programador-web-php-desde-cero&Itemid=193).

No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta si fue de ayuda.

Comment: Tengo un problema al obtener el $json, cuando uso $json = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response); me devuelve en formato HTML y no en Json y por consecuencia cuando trato de obtener el array con $array = json_decode( $json, $assoc = true ); no me devielve nada.

Comment: Tengo problemas con el plugin Json Rest API V2, instale la version 1 y modifique la linea $response = wp_remote_get('http://local.wp.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'); por $response = wp_remote_get('http://local.wp.dev/wp-json/posts/'); y ya pude obtener el formato json

Comment: Hola de nuevo, no e logrado resolver mi problema, estoy atorado a la hora de convertir el arrat a xml, ya que lo e intentado con fluidxml pero me da un error, despues intente con otros metodos y tambien me dan error , creo que es el mismo, ya que los nodos del array o algo asi alguno o varios empiezan con un numero y al convertirlo da error ya que en xml es invalido empezar con un numero el nombre de un nodo. El array lo e obtenido convirtiendo el json a array como me dijiste arriba, como podria resolver este problema?

Comment: Te sugeriría que actualices tu pregunta, incluyendo lo que has intentado ya, así como los mensajes de error o excepciones que está arrojando, con datos de muestra para poder reproducirlo y ayudarte a encontrar la solución. De otro modo solo estaríamos adivinando.

Answer (score 1):

¿Y si accedes directamente al **RSS** que ya existe y tiene formato XML?

Por ejemplo:

```
http://example.com/?feed=rss
```

Más información en https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

Comment: nota: para obtener el texto completo del post hay que activar la opción en el admin (full text, texto completo)

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacerlo instalando el plugin **WP All Export** puedes descargarlo aquí: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-export/

Una vez lo hayas descargado descomprime el archivo wp-all-export.zip y sube su contenido a /wp-content/plugins/, despues entras al backoffice de tu wordpress vas al apartado plugins y lo instalas.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Deberias incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta que esta en el link que provees, El link puede romperse y la respuesta se volvería inútil. Saludos!

Comment: No busco nada de plugins, estoy utilizando uno pero el detalle es que cada vez que aga un nuevo post tengo que estar generando el archivo xml, yo necesito un código en PHP que pueda añadir a WordPress por medio de un hook así cada vez que publique algo automáticamente se genere el archivo xml actualizado